# css displays in DW CS5.5 live view but not in browser preview

Tags: html, css, jsp

I am developing a JSP based web application using DW CS5.5. The background color & font are defined in maincss.css file which has been attached to the jsp code file. The background color & fonts show up correctly in DW live view but not in browser or browser preview . I have already searched and tried no. of suggested solutions but it hasn't helped. If the bgcolor and Text font are defined in html code in body tag, it works but not through css. My code is as below:

maincss.css file is saved in WEB-INF folder.

maincss code:

```
@charset "utf-8";
.bodystyle {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: white;
    background-color: #336666
}
```

HTML/ JSP code:

```
.
.
<script language="javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
<link href="WEB-INF/maincss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</HEAD>
<body  background="" class="bodystyle"
                    onload=document.NewUser.user.focus()>

<%@ include file="menu1.htm" %>
.
.
```

I feel that browser is not able to locate or implement the maincss file but not able to figure out why.

Please help to locate and rectify the error in my code.

Thanks in advance.
SK

Comment: Go in your browser press F12 (or right click "inspect element") and look if your file is loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Move your css file under another folder. The WEB-INF folder is not accessible because files under it are not directly visible for the public

Comment: Thank you soooomuch Taha. I moved the css file to a new CSS folder outside WEB-INF and it worked. Thanks a lot for your help. I was baffled over the issue for past so many days.